# Horrible Iceweasel and Opera performance when watching youtube

Tags: performance, youtube

I have 64-bit Debian on laptop with Intel Core 2 Duo T9300 2.5GHz, Nvidia Quadro NVS140M GPU and 4GB RAM. For now - im on vacation and im using 3G USB modem.

I have relatively slow but high quality stable 80kB/s (640kb/s) connection and it is enough to watch youtube 360p without any problems under Windows 7 on same machine. Youtube player and other video services work perfect, response on my clicks is instant. I also tried to watch youtube on very old 900MHz PIII desktop with same USB modem - no problem at all.

However - under Debian (Iceweasel or Opera) - **all video players seem to work very inefficient and most of them freeze my browser for few seconds**. Pause button has lag too.

I noticed that my browsers load diffrent youtube player (it's not HTML5 player like under windows).

I also tried to connect my laptop via ethernet to windows computer with shared internet (from same USB modem), so this is not USB modem driver fault.

My GPU is installed correctly and it seem to work with high performance.It deals with modern Gnome with fancy animations without performance problems, but I'm using Gnome Classic because modern one is too buggy when I run OpenGL app in windowed mode.

**What can I do to improve youtube performance?**

Im really confused that interned browsing on my relatively fast laptop works slower than old 900MHz PIII desktop with Windows XP.

Comment: Have you tried chrome or firefox?  I don' have any problems watching youtube with either of those.

Comment: I just installed Chrome. HTML5 player appeared and it works smooth like under Windows, but I'm not fan of Chrome. I don't think that Firefox can help, I think Iceweasel is basically renamed Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, supposedly it's just firefox rebranded.  I have a big quad core, but firefox 30.0 (fedora) plays youtube fine with < 5% CPU usage.  On [this page](https://www.youtube.com/html5?gl=CA) I get "The HTML5 player is currently used when possible" but only 2 of the 6 types are checked with firefox.  With chrome 36.0, all six types are checked.  IMO chrome is the most trouble free choice on linux and tends to do better on those kinds of "standards implementation" tests (e.g. [acid3](http://acid3.acidtests.org/); actually in these versions both get 100% on that).